# can't install python lxml

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-14.04

When I install lxml with `pip install lxml` I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS‬, python 2.7.6
How to find the -lz library?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved installing the libz-dev library, -lz is libz-dev.